# understanding the behavior of login to facebook with firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, angularfire2

we are using sign in using facebook with firebase as backend. Our app let people browse content without sign in. but if someone try to purchase something then it kicks the login flow by showing a model popup. the login page typescript looks like below

```
constructor(  private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private fb: Facebook) {

                afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
                  if (!user) {   
                    return;
                  }

                  core.user = new User(user.uid, user.displayName, user.photoURL, user.email, true, false)
                  this.createUser(user.uid)
                });
  }
```

overall idea is if user never used the app then we create an account for the user in the firebase DB else we just return from the subscribe. On running this app 2nd time what I see is that when login page comes i automatically get a valid account detail of me. I am wondering how does it know?

Comment: Are you call the `afAuth.auth.signOut();` method?  In you firebase console, you can found the auth services setting.

Comment: what signout has to do with my question?

Comment: anyone on this?